# DataGridView not updating/refrshing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am using c# and winforms, i am not using any type of database every thing is add by code.

Hello i have a DataGridView called `_GridView` with one column called IP.

IP is the only column and is a string

I have the following code to add a row and update the grid:

```
    public void AddUser(string IP)
    {
        _GridView.Rows.Add(IP);
        _GridView.Update();
        _GridView.Refresh();
    }
```

For some reason the grid is not updating/refreshing, i am not receiving any type of error and IP is not null.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Could be a type error? Could you show us how you create your columns because we're in the dark here. Is `IP` the first column and is it of type string?

Comment: @RobbieVercammen 'IP' is the only column and is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like editing the datarow collection directly.

Alternatively, try using a `BindingList<User>` as a `DataSource` for you grid.
Since we don't have a lot of background, method `ExampleColumnSetup()` is how I would setup the `IP` column:

```
BindingList<User> source = new BindingList<User>();

public void ExampleColumnSetup()
{
    DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    column.DataPropertyName = "IP";
    column.Name = "User";
    _GridView.Columns.Add(column);
}
public void AddUser(string ip)
{
    source.add(new User(IP = ip));

    _GridView.DataSource = null;
    _GridView.DataSource = source;
}
public class User()
{
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public User(string IP)
    {
        this.IP = IP;
    }
}
```

If you add a new user to the `source` list, the grid should update itself.
I don't have any winforms application to test this so sorry for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should call _GridView.EndEdit(); before you can refresh it again, keep me updated

Comment: @pekira in that case you should have some kind of data source since it needs to save it somewhere, try to give me this info or have an look on data sources for the datagridview

Comment: I think that's not the problem because another program that uses this code InfoGrid.Rows.Add("Test", Test.Count); and is working